# merge 2 series with different indexes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing, series

I have 2 series with different indexes but the same length of 638.

series `fc`'s output is

```
1888    4.899912
1889    4.900162
1890    4.900141
1891    4.900142
1892    4.900142
          ...   
2521    4.900142
2522    4.900142
2523    4.900142
2524    4.900142
2525    4.900142
Name: predicted_mean, Length: 638, dtype: float64
```

and series `fc_series`'s output is

```
Date
2020-12-16   NaN
2020-12-17   NaN
2020-12-18   NaN
2020-12-21   NaN
2020-12-22   NaN
              ..
2023-06-26   NaN
2023-06-27   NaN
2023-06-28   NaN
2023-06-29   NaN
2023-06-30   NaN
Name: predicted_mean, Length: 638, dtype: float64
```

I tried using this code line

```
fc_series = pd.Series(fc, index=test_data.index)
```

I want `fc`'s values in place of the NaN values in `fc_series`. I am struggling with the indexing part of this and would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there.

The issue is that creating a Series from another Series and passing an Index will perform index alignment, which you precisely don't want here.

Instead, just pass `fc`'s values:

```
out = pd.Series(fc.to_numpy(), index=fc_series.index)
```

Or, if you want to modify `fc_series` in place:

```
fc_series[:] = fc.to_numpy()
```

Output:

```
2020-12-16    4.899912
2020-12-17    4.900162
2020-12-18    4.900141
2020-12-21    4.900142
2020-12-22    4.900142
                ...   
2023-06-26    4.900142
2023-06-27    4.900142
2023-06-28    4.900142
2023-06-29    4.900142
2023-06-30    4.900142
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {1888: 4.899912, 1889: 4.900162, 1890: 4.900141, 1891: 4.900142, 1892: 4.900142}
s1 = pd.Series(data1)
data2 = {'2020-12-16': float('nan'), '2020-12-17': float('nan'), '2020-12-18': float('nan'), 
         '2020-12-21': float('nan'), '2020-12-22': float('nan')}
s2 = pd.Series(data2)
```

`s1`

```
1888    4.899912
1889    4.900162
1890    4.900141
1891    4.900142
1892    4.900142
dtype: float64
```

`s2`

```
2020-12-16   NaN
2020-12-17   NaN
2020-12-18   NaN
2020-12-21   NaN
2020-12-22   NaN
dtype: float64
```

---

**Code**

If s2 is all NaN, use this code.

```
s1.set_axis(s2.index)
```

output:

```
2020-12-16    4.899912
2020-12-17    4.900162
2020-12-18    4.900141
2020-12-21    4.900142
2020-12-22    4.900142
dtype: float64
```

---

If some of the values in s2 are NaN and you want to fill them with the values from s1 only when they are NaN, use this code.

```
s2.fillna(s1.set_axis(s2.index))
```